# Dynamic rerouting and circular dependency with Mostjs

Tags: xstream-js, mostjs

It is evident that xstream, with the two methods `addListener` and `removeListener`, is able to reroute streams (change their sources and sinks) dynamically. I see no equivalent with mostjs. Does most only let you lay out the routing of the streams once? If so, is this static nature what allows mostjs to optimize for such superior performance?

Also, xstream uses an `imitate` method that lets it feature circular dependencies. Is there any way to achieve circular dependency with mostjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many functions in most.js that operate on both a `Source` and a `Sink`, e.g., `map()`, which transforms all the events in a stream, acts as a `Sink` by consuming events, and as a `Source` when producing new event values after applying a function to them. `observe()` is an example of a particular kind of `Sink` that consumes events, and passes them to a function you provide.

Most.js `Streams` are not active until you consume them, by using one of the "terminal" combinators, `observe`, `drain`, or `reduce`. When you call one of those, the `Stream` sends a signal in the `Source-Sink` chain to the `Source` at the very beginning of the chain. That producer `Source` will then begin producing events.

Events are then propagated synchronously from the `Source` through the `Source-Sink` chain by a simple method call.

Thus, you could provide your own "listener" function to a `map` which would transform the events.

There are many factors contributing to most.js’s performance.

> The simple call stack event propagation architecture, plus hoisting
>   `try/catch` out of combinator implementations were two of the earliest
>   and biggest performance improvements.
>
> Most.js performs several other optimizations automatically, based on
>   algebraic equivalences. A relatively well-known example is combining
>   multiple `map` operations, e.g. `map(g, map(f, stream))`, into a
>   single `map` by doing function composition on `f` and `g`.
>
> The operation also combines multiple `filter` operations, multiple
>   `merge` operations, multiple `take` and `skip`, among others. These
>   optimizations reduce the number of method calls needed to propagate an
>   event from producer to consumer.

[See this interview with Brian Cavalier](https://survivejs.com/blog/most-interview/)

Most.js itself doesn’t handle circular dependencies, but it is totally possible using [`most-proxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/most-proxy). [Motorcycle](https://github.com/motorcyclets/motorcycle) does this to create its cycle in its `run` package.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this issue regarding `xstream.js` `imitate` in `most.js`?https://github.com/cujojs/most/issues/308